# Encrypting user's data and its database

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption

Can you suggest me CakePHP 2.5 encryption plugin/library/example?

I want to encrypt user input and store it in encrypted form in database record. Then data is decrypted to end user on will on user's screen. All is done with user's created password key, not stored in database, and entered each time as user login to front end app. All is about that owner of hosting, or owner of app, can not decrypt end user's data without his password key. I need some sort of algorithm encryption/decryption library.

Comment: As with many encryption questions: What is your threat model? What data are you trying to protect, and from whom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `password_hash` if you have PHP 5.5 or above. Here is the documentation:
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.password-hash.php
If not, use bcrypt. [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)